# How to change authentication for Office Communications Server 2007 R2 so, google smtp can be used for authentification?

Tags: ms-office-communicator

We have problem with integration between Microsoft Communication Server 2007 (office communicator) and Outlook 2007 because our email address is different from our domain name (ie. email address is user@gmail.com, but our domain name for signing in is user@domainname.something).
Is there a way to configure MS Office Communication Server 2007 so authentication can be used with gmail ?
We are not using MS Exchange server.

When Communicator signed in we have message
"*There was a problem connecting to Microsoft Office Outlook. Your Outlook profile is not configured correctly. Contact your system administrator with this information.*" and during our research we find out that our emails and communicator account are different 
(like described previously). Because of that we cannot use feature like message history.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to integrate here? Does Office Communicator work but you want the OCS plugin to work in Outlook? Or dod you just want Office Communicator to automatically configure itself for your users?

Comment: I try to enable message history for start.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you'll need to follow this KB article to fix the issue, sort of.  You still won't have message history, but you won't get the error either.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951644/en-us